# Elasticsearch: Spreading files across data paths

Tags: elasticsearch

There are lots of docs talking about the distribution of shards across nodes in a cluster, but very little about the actual usage of **multiple data paths within nodes**.
It is clear that a shard cannot be split over different paths, but *WHEN* and *HOW* does Elasticsearch (say 7.6) decide to create or to move a shard from one data path to another (across nodes, or within the same node)?

It is written that when a disk reaches a given watermark (e.g. 90%) the system decides to reallocate shards.
BUT does this include the possibility to reallocate them within the same node, i.e. moving it to a new empty disk, for instance?

Is it possible to tell Elastic to use a given data path when creating a new index, for instance?

Is there any clear document explaining these behaviours in detail?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The answer varies a bit by version, and may change in future. This answer applies to all released and supported versions at time of writing, which is versions 6.5 to 7.6. None of these versions move shards between disks within a node. They all pick a path for each shard the first time it's assigned to the node and that's where it stays. If a disk hits the high watermark then Elasticsearch will relocate one or more of the shards on the fullest data path onto different nodes, and those nodes will select a data path with enough space for the shard and will generally prefer emptier paths.

Although this doesn't sound ideal, in practice it's not too big of a problem. You can combine multiple disks together (e.g. using RAID 0 or LVM) into a single logical volume, avoiding concerns of balancing between data paths within a node. Alternatively, if you really want more control over the allocation of shards to individual disks, you can run multiple smaller nodes on each host each of which only uses one disk. You can even combine these approaches.

Comment: Just one question, @Dave: even though you specify that "this doesn't sound ideal", the fact that "If a disk hits the high watermark then Elasticsearch will relocate one or more of the shards on the fullest data path onto different nodes, and those nodes will select a data path with enough space for the shard and will generally prefer emptier paths", this would imply that provided you have empty disks in your cluster, it will never run out of space, or deactivate shards? Correct?

Comment: The problem - given your explanation - could arise only if you have a one-node cluster, since in that case shards cannot be relocated o other nodes, and "None of these versions move shards between disks within a node", correct? And finally: is there any official document reporting the behavior that you have explained? Thank you again.

Comment: In most cases, yes, as long as you've the space and time to move shards around then Elasticsearch should fit your data in. This isn't 100% guaranteed, however, and becomes increasingly difficult as you approach capacity. It's much simpler if you have only a single data path per node.

Comment: And yes, if you have a one-node cluster then you will see problems.

Comment: Thank you again, @Dave. I expect that in future releases Elastic guys will address this issue, as it seems that - given these premises - the multiple paths feature is somehow half-dveloped... It looks a bit weird that relocating shards across nodes is so efficient, while relocating them across different data paths has so many limitations.

Comment: Ah, I forgot: do you know where can I find some official words about that behavior? (you know, for my clients...)

Comment: No, I don't think this is documented anywhere outside of the source code.